# Set DIV height dynamically based on viewport height

Tags: jquery, height, viewport

I'm trying to set a div's height to 30% of the viewport height and I would very much like to scale it when the height of the viewport changes.

I tried setting min-height: 30%; height:30% but it is not working.

I took a look at JQuery's height(); but I just don't know how to get started.

Thanks.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
function thirty_pc() {
    var height = $(window).height();
    var thirtypc = (30 * height) / 100;
    thirtypc = parseInt(thirtypc) + 'px';
    $("div").css('height',thirtypc);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    thirty_pc();
    $(window).bind('resize', thirty_pc);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the work... Liam's answer is accepted. I can't get it to work though: http://jsfiddle.net/QqwCM/1/

Comment: It wont work in jsfiddle becuase it runs in iframe, if you put that code into a .html file with  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> included it works fine. Make it $(window).height() in the thirty_pc function definition (as changed above) for full cross-browser support.

Answer (score 20):

This is basically Liam Bailey's answer, but with a thirty_pc() that should be both faster and more concise:

```
function thirty_pc() {
    $("div").css('height', '' + Math.round(.3 * window.height()));
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    thirty_pc();
    $(window).bind('resize', thirty_pc);
});
```

If you like it, please still accept Liam's, but upvote mine. :)

Comment: Oh and i made a new one not a comment because i couldn't multi-line in comments. I'm not trying to steal anybody's credit here...

Comment: Obviously the percentage calculation could be condensed into the $.css method call, I did it the way I did it because it is easier for a newbie to see what is being done and how, I am no expert on the difference between parseInt and Math.Round in terms of speed, but I think the difference is less than worth worrying about. And @bbg no it needn't be $(window).height() because the window element exists in javascript, and is not jQuery specific.

Comment: @Liam: interesting observations; +1 on your answer too.  I keep getting a 'function not defined' error in both FF and chrome, but when I wrap the window in a jQuery object, I get it to work.

Comment: You are right bbg, I should have used $(window) anyway, when you are working in jQuery I suppose it is a good idea to use its wrappers for objects, for better cross-browser support.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onresize=function(){
    $("#selectedDiv").height( ($(window).height()*.3) );
}
```

Comment: How is your answer different than the accepted one?

Comment: Just posted how i do it with less

Answer (score 0):

This one works 100% for viewport height of any div, section that has this class using Jquery.
Use additional function to adjust height to 30% currently it is 100% please promote if you like it.

```
function thirty_pc() {
    $(".introduction").css({'height':($(window).height())+'px'});
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    thirty_pc();
    $(window).bind('resize', thirty_pc);
});
```