# Set a div's height to the height of the browser

Tags: html, css, height

I'm trying to make a list of slide divs that will have content within them, something quite similar to what the Foo Fighter's have going on, on their website: http://www.foofighters.com/us/discography

The main thing I'd like to figure out is how to have each "slide" auto-adjust to be the proper height when the browser is resized. You can check it out yourself on the discography page I linked. Is there a way to accomplish this? I'm assuming it would be a javascript/jquery thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to know that to have a 100% height on a block element, all of the parents must also be set to 100% height.

For example, my if html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">
   <div id="myDiv">This is my div!</div>
</div>    

</body>
</html>
```

The CSS required to make myDiv 100% height would be

```
<style type="text/css">
   html, body, #wrapper, #myDiv { height: 100%; }
</style>
```

Notice all of the parents of #myDiv are also set to 100% height.  This is the key to achieving 100% dynamic height for block elements.

Answer (score 1):

An example of getting a `div` to resize to browser window height:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#mydiv {
    height: 100%;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="mydiv">TEST</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Tested in Chrome, IE9, Firefox and Opera, all running on Windows. IE9 required the DOCTYPE to be specified in order to work correctly, the other browsers didn't seem to care.

JQuery alternative: [Set DIV height dynamically based on viewport height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6564752/set-div-height-dynamically-based-on-viewport-height)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on IE! Does that mean I can still use <!DOCTYPE html> for it to work on IE, or do I need to use one of the ones that W3Schools lists. Like 1.0 strict, etc.